# How to get specific string from string in php not any answer on web

Tags: php

How to get specific string from string in **php**? I have one string "Hello", so I want only "He". How is it possible with function or other method?

Comment: Google: `PHP substr()`

Comment: I'm new so please explain details. please give any example.

Comment: `not any answer on web` - you're kidding me

Comment: There are plenty of questions similar to yours, it's not our job to teach you,  Rizier123 gave you a hint, google it and you'll find plenty of explanations and examples.

Comment: no no but not specific any answer may i can't understand that.

Comment: Just detail more your question. Do you always wants the 2 firsts characters of a string?

Comment: no i want string that i entered.

Comment: [Simply scroll down to the link and you'll find **lot of examples** over there.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: ok i will try for that and so many thanks.  Uchiha

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about string functions.

```
<?php
     $startPosition = 0; // INITIALIZE FROM WHICH POINT YOU WANT TO TAKE CHARACTERS
     $characters = 2; // INITIALIZE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS YOU REQUIRED
     $string = 'Hello'; // INITALIZE YOUR STRING 
     $string1 = substr($string, $startPosition, $characters); // STRING FUNCTION
?>
```